# Jquery not loading html page at button click

Tags: jquery, ajax, button

I am trying to load a html file at button click using ajax and jquery but click is not loading it.Below is the code.

ajax.aspx file:-

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="dictionary"></div>
    <div class="letters">
        <div class="button" id="letter-a">
            <h3>A</h3>
            <button type="button">Load</button>
        </div>
        <div class="button" id="letter-b">
            <h3>B</h3>
            <button type="button">Load</button>
        </div>
        <div class="button" id="letter-c">
            <h3>C</h3>
            <button type="button">Load</button>
        </div>
        <div class="button" id="letter-d">
            <h3>D</h3>
            <button type="button">Load</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

ajax.js file:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#letter-a .button').click(function () {
        $('#dictionary').load('html_ajax.htm');
    });
});
```

But its not working. what i am missing?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$('#letter-a .button').click(function () {
```

to

```
$('#letter-a button').click(function() {
```

You are using class selector for selecting the `button` tag. your selector selects the elements that have `button` class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the . from the .button - .button means something with a class of button.

This means "look for an element with the id "letter-a" and the class "button".

```
 $('#letter-a .button').click(function () { }
```

This means "look for a a button element contained within an element with id "letter-a".

```
$('#letter-a button').click(function () { }
```